# CSS3 unsorted list, submenu

Tags: html, css

[image: Capture]

Please see the capture. As you can see the first pulldown menu works properly, the sub-menu did show up and it displays in horizontally but not listing vertically.

CSS Code:

```
#topbanner    { 
width:100%; height:25px; margin:0;position:relative;background-color:#4c4e5a;display: block;}

.rightmenu, .rightmenu ul, .rightmenu li, .rightmenu a { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; outline: none; }

.rightmenu { float: right; }    
.rightmenu li a{
display: block; padding: 0 14px; margin: 3px 0;color: #f3f3f3;background-color: #4c4e5a;}

.rightmenu ul {
    position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
background-color: #4c4e5a;
left: auto;
right:0;
width:180px;
}

.rightmenu ul ul {
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
right: 100%;
top: 0%;
background-color: #4c4e5a;
width:180px;
}

.rightmenu li:hover > a { color: #8fde62; } 
.rightmenu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; } 

.rightmenu ul li{
height:0;
overflow:hidden;
padding: 0; 
}

.rightmenu li:hover > ul li {  
height: 25px;
overflow: visible; 
padding:0;
} 

.rightmenu ul li a { 
white-space: nowrap;
border: none;
}
```

I have omitted some styling in order to make the code short for you. (like shadow, border style, and round corner)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are gonna wanna throw a

```
clear: both
```

on your ul ul li

Comment: The width of those items didn't exceed the width of the container. So they, as inline elements, didn't clear to the next line. Setting clear both makes them pop to the next line regardless of width.

Comment: another question: it did successfully displayed the vertical menu, whenever I clicked on the second items (hardware inventory/6789), it will display another submenu. (like Administration)

Comment: like the attached picture, one the left, when I hover Task Overview, it will display the second menu. What I thought, should be menu was hidden in the background?